# How to call methods in functional interfaces without .Method()

Tags: java

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyFunctionalInterface_1 F;
        MyFunctionalInterface_2 G;
        F = X::Method;
        int i = F.Method(5);
        System.out.println(i);
        G = new X()::Method;
        G.Method();
    }
}

class X{
    public static int Method(double x){
        return (int)(x*x*x);
    }

    public void Method(){
        System.out.println("Huy sosi");
    }
}

@FunctionalInterface
interface MyFunctionalInterface_1{
    int Method(double x);
}

@FunctionalInterface
interface MyFunctionalInterface_2{
    void Method();
}
```

How can I call function as `F()` or `G()`?

I was doing exam question (translate from Russian):

> Write an entity declaration F, G and X in Java so that the following
>   code fragment compiles without errors
>
> ```
> "F = X::Method; int i = F(0.0); G = new X()::Method; G();"
> ```

I don't know how can I call them this way. () and (0.0)
Or maybe I should use something different and not just functional interfaces.
I am not specialist in java. Can you help me?

Comment: Best I can tell, they are trying to trick you by using confusing different meanings of `G`. In which case, the answer is to add a static method `public static void G() { }`

Comment: I think it is really confusing question, because there are multiple entities of G (one is for functional interface and one is for static function). And same for F.
I was asked to help in Java, but I haven’t written a million years on it...

Answer (score 5):

It's possible like this, exploiting the rules around the [meaning of a name](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.5):

```
static int F(double d) {
  return 0;
}

static void G() {}

static class X {
  void method();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  Consumer<X> F;
  Runnable G;

  F = X::Method; int i = F(0.0); G = new X()::Method; G();
}
```

Note that `F(0.0)` *isn't* invoking the consumer, and `G()` *isn't* running the runnable. However, this does meet the criterion of "compiles without errors".

---

After a bit of thought, I came up with a way to define it so that the method invocations do the same as the functional methods would:

```
class X {
  static int F(double x) {
    return 0;
  }

  static int Method(double x) {
    return F(x);
  }

  static void G() {}

  void Method() {
    G();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    DoubleToIntFunction F;
    Runnable G;

    F = X::Method; int i = F(0.0); G = new X()::Method; G();
  }
}
```

What a mess.